Give Form Section a Background Color/Gradient
This is my code:
Form {
  Section {} // regular section no background

  Section { // <--- want this section to have a background color
     Text("Hello")
  }
  .background(Gradient(colors: [.teal, .cyan, .green]).opacity(0.6))

} // Do not want background on form only on an individual section

This only puts a background on the Text(), which makes sense, but how do I get it to apply the background just the section

You need to use .listRowBackground and apply a gradient as the background style. See below:
Form {
      Section {} // regular section no background

      Section { // <--- want this section to have a background color
         Text("Hello")
      }
      .listRowBackground(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.teal, .cyan, .green]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
        
} // Do not want background on form only on an individual section



Say I had this
Section {
                    
                    Text("MVFR")
                    
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 100)
                .listRowBackground(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.green, .cyan, .teal, .blue]), startPoint:.leading, endPoint: .trailing))

how would i get the Text to be on the bottom left of the view almost hugging the parent section view - i tried offseting, using .frame- cant figure it out

@Yuda Since this is a different question, I suggest creating a new post to handle it
